# How to solve 'MapRoute uses'. {controller}/{name} taking all action call in same route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using

> 'routes.MapRoute'

to take one parameter without calling the action name. it works fine, but now my problem is whenever I wanted to use any other action form the same controller it's always calling the same action that is described on the 'routes.MapRoute'.

My ajax calling for all other action has GET type. but still, it's calling the same action that is described in the routes.MapRoute.

//This is my custom route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "kuenstler",
        "kuenstler/{name}",
        new { controller = "kuenstler", action = "Index" }
    );
```

//my default route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id 
= 
    UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The first route will be called from a link attribute from another page so I need to get the name from there but without the action name.

```
<a href="kuenstler/name-lastname">link</a>
```

action that needs to get the name from the calling.

```
 public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetKuenstlerGalleryData(int? artistId, string 
     direction)
    {
    /// some code
    }
```

Every time I am clicking the link

> //localhost:50519/Kuenstler/firstname-lastname.

I am getting the name in my Index. Then I am calling the second action from javascript with GET  type. But every time it's coming in the Index with the calling action name as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But every time it's coming in the Index with the calling action name as parameter.

Of course it does, your requests path perfectly fits the kuenstler route template.
You can map specific route for GetKuenstlerGalleryData action right before 'kuenstler' one. Ex.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "kuenstler-gallery-data",
        "kuenstler/GetKuenstlerGalleryData",
        new { controller = "kuenstler", action = "GetKuenstlerGalleryData" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
        "kuenstler",
        "kuenstler/{name}",
        new { controller = "kuenstler", action = "Index" }
    );
```

or use separate template, ex.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "kuenstler-gallery-data",
        "kuenstler-gallery-data",
        new { controller = "kuenstler", action = "GetKuenstlerGalleryData" }
    );
```

or even use [attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: If I have 5 actions on that controller? then do I have to make 5 different mapRoute for them

Comment: @MahfuzurRahman is GetKuenstlerGalleryData a detail view of some kuenstler/name (whatever it is), or is it some kind of a list view? Guess you didn't considered your routing scheme enough. Depending on your answer routing template may become "kuenstler/{name}/{action}" or "kuenstler/{action}/{name}"

Comment: Whenever I click on this link //localhost:50519/Kuenstler/firstname-lastname.
In the Index(string name) name= "firstname-lastname". Then in the Index view loading i need to pass this name to my GetKuenstlerGalleryData(name,someother,andother). But every time I am making a ajax call to GetKuenstlerGalleryData(name,someother,andother). Its going to the same Index with parameter name ="GetKuenstlerGalleryData".

Comment: @MahfuzurRahman try to use  "kuenstler/{name}/{action}" template and then use "kuenstler/firstname-lastname/GetKuenstlerGalleryData" path to retrieve gallery data via ajax

Comment: My problem is whatever I am writing after controller name Kuenstler/{whatever} it's calling the action defined in the Map route.

Comment: Did you change the route template to "kuenstler/{name}/{action}"?

Comment: Solved this problem using "attribute routing" :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192058/discussion-between-mahfuzur-rahman-and-leff).